# Limit string width by breaking into multiple lines with Python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am using python to generate a test file used for programming.  In this file, I have several auto-generated comments.  Problem is, some of these comments can be quite long, and the software which reads the file generates an error if a line is too long.

What I am looking for is a method of breaking a string with '\n# '.  The location of these line returns should limit the width of any one line to be less than a certain width.  Below is an example of what I want to do.  I need code that generates "broken_line" from "long_line".

```
long_line = "# alpha || bravo || charlie || delta || echo are the first 5 elements of NATO"

broken_line = "# alpha || bravo || charlie ||\n# delta || echo are the first \n# 5 elements of NATO"


>>>print long_line
# alpha || bravo || charlie || delta || echo are the first 5 elements of NATO

>>>print broken_line
# alpha || bravo || charlie ||
# delta || echo are the first
# 5 elements of NATO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`textwrap` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) to wrap lines to a maximum width. You can specify `'# '` as indentation to prefix your lines properly:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> long_line = "# alpha || bravo || charlie || delta || echo are the first 5 elements of NATO"
>>> textwrap.fill(long_line, 30, subsequent_indent='# ')
'# alpha || bravo || charlie ||\n# delta || echo are the first\n# 5 elements of NATO'
>>> print textwrap.fill(long_line, 30, subsequent_indent='# ')
# alpha || bravo || charlie ||
# delta || echo are the first
# 5 elements of NATO
```

The module is very flexible, do read the documentation to see what knobs you want to twiddle for the perfect result.

Comment: That is a very nice module and it did exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [textwrap-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)

```
In [6]: import textwrap

In [7]: long_line = "# alpha || bravo || charlie || delta || echo are the first 5 elements of NATO"

In [8]: textwrap.wrap(long_line, width=50)
Out[8]: 
['# alpha || bravo || charlie || delta || echo are',
 'the first 5 elements of NATO']
```